# Saving a picture in Python

Tags: python, image, file, save, jython

In Python I have created a picture using the "makeEmpyPicture" function in Python. How do I save this as an external file. I have a string that I want to call it. All I want to do is to be able to save it without importing any libraries into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def savePict(pict, name):
  filehandle=getMediaPath(name)
  writePictureTo(pict,filehandle)
```

**EDIT :**

I guess last line of your suggestion should be:

```
writePictureTo(pict,file)
```

rather than

```
writePictureTo(pict,filename).
```

Otherwise the variable **file** wouldnt be used

Answer (score 0):

I guess what Rob suggests is that:

- filename = 'myPicture.png'
- file = your saving directory

Then, the function getMediaPath(filename) would look like this:

```
getMediaPath(filename):
    temp_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"../../YourCurrentFolder")
    saving_dir = temp_dir + '/' + filename
    return saving_dir
```